# Creating Array of Arrays in Azure Data Factory

Tags: arrays, azure-data-factory, expression

I have a requirement to create a date array in Azure Data Factory as below. The start and End Date will be provided and the resultant array of array should look like the below

```
[["01-Jan-2022","31-Mar-2022"],["01-Apr-2022","30-Jun-2022"]]
```

the interval between the dates need to be 3 months each.

I am providing a start date and an end date in the parameters 'StartDate' and 'EndDate'. I have tried doing this using a For Each Loop, but couldn't get it through.

I need to loop through this array of dates and create a SOAP request with each set of start and end dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create variables in pipeline like in below screenshot.
  [image]
- Take a until activity and give the below expression

```
@greater(addDays(addToTime(variables('new_date'),6,'Month'),-1),pipeline().parameters.EndDate)
```

Until activity runs till this expression evaluates to false. Inside until activity, take four set variable activities.

[image]

- Store the value of variable `new_date1` and `arr_str` in `new_date` and `temp` respectively using **set variable activities**.
- Take another **set variable activity** and store the value for `arr_str` using below expression

`@concat(variables('temp'),',',string(createArray(formatDateTime(variables('new_date'),'dd-MMM-yyyy'),formatDateTime(addDays(addToTime(variables('new_date'),3,'Month'),-1),'dd-MMM-yyyy'))))`

- Take another **set variable activity** and store the value for `new_date1` using below expression
  `@addToTime(variables('new_date'),3,'Month')`.
- Take set variable activity outside the loop and connect it sequentially with until activity. Expression for `arr_out` is given as below.

```
@json(concat('[',substring(variables('arr_str'),1,add(length(variables('arr_str')),-1)),']'))
```

[image]

The `arr_out` array will give the required output between start date and end date.

Comment: It works fine with one problem only if that can be fixed ? The increment i want to give is dynamic like 6Months or 12 Months or 3 Months. In that case the final array created contains atleast 3-5 items beyond the current date. So the end date is set to Current date and in case of 3 months increment it should end on 31st March, but it progressess to 31-Mar-2025. I have tried many things in the Until criteria to cut it down but no use. Any Help ? Ex. Start Date: 01-01-2023 EndDate: UTCNow(). Result array goes upto 31-Mar-2025

Comment: All Good... I fixed it for my scenario... working perfectly for now. An improvement could be to look for Quarters / Half years and stop there so given input date of FEb-2024, the first array item should be 31-Mar-2024 (Provided an interval of 3 Months), currently it will go to Apr-2024 for the first quarter. But as i said working for me for now... All Goood ... :)